# remove elements from a List of case class structure when found duplicate scala using foldleft

Tags: scala

Remove both the object of case class if found duplicate in scala

Example list as follows:

```
val pets = List(
  Pet("cat", "sassy", 2), Pet("cat", "bella", 3),
  Pet("dog", "poppy", 3), Pet("dog", "bodie", 4), Pet("dog", "poppy", 2),
  Pet("bird", "coco", 2), Pet("bird", "kiwi", 1),
  Pet("hen", "kiwi", 2), Pet("horse", "kiwi", 1),
  Pet("cow", "mow", 2)
)
```

I want to check the list for duplicates and remove them from the list. In this case my list will only have one values, and in this example it would be the values `Pet("cow", "mow", 2)`, and others will go away. here `Pet("hen", "kiwi", 2)`, `Pet("horse", "kiwi", 1)` not considered because "kiwi" is repeated.

```
case class Pet(species: String, name: String, age: Int)

val pets = List(
  Pet("cat", "sassy", 2), Pet("cat", "bella", 3),
  Pet("dog", "poppy", 3), Pet("dog", "bodie", 4), Pet("dog", "poppy", 2),
  Pet("bird", "coco", 2), Pet("bird", "kiwi", 1),
  Pet("hen", "kiwi", 2), Pet("horse", "kiwi", 1),
  Pet("cow", "mow", 2)
)

def customEqualsPet(x : Pet, y: Pet) = (x.species == y.species || x.name== y.name)
val petsOut = pets.foldLeft(Nil : List[Pet]) {(list, item) =>
    val exists = list.find(x => customEqualsPet(item, x))
    
    if (exists.isEmpty) {
      item :: list
    } else {
      println("once......"+list)
      println("once......"+item)
      list.filter(u=>{(u.name!=item.name) || (u.species!=item.species)})
    }
  }.reverse
println(cc)
```

seems to mess with the output. Help appreciated
Expected output

```
List( Pet("cow", "mow", 2))
```

Comment: here species name is different and it's treated as unique.

Comment: species can not repeated or   name canot repeated ,Age can be repeated

Comment: where are you using spark in this ?

Comment: no I am not using spark .only core scala

Comment: Expected Outputfrom above:List( Pet("cow", "mow", 2)) .Note: name or species  canot be repeated in case class of list element.That means same name or same species  type is not allowed as element to build the another list

Comment: "How do I solve X by doing Y" is called an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), because doing Y might not be the best way to solve X.  In this case, `foldLeft` is not the best way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option you have, is to first find all names and species you want to remove:

```
val speciesToRemove = pets.groupBy(_.species).filter(_._2.length > 1).keySet
val namesToRemove = pets.groupBy(_.name).filter(_._2.length > 1).keySet
```

And then filter by them:

```
pets.filterNot(pet => speciesToRemove.contains(pet.species) || namesToRemove.contains(pet.name))
```

Code run for that in [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/zXtlf6sYRwWa9ygyQbPH1w/1).

Comment: for your above solution,I want to drop species if found duplicate or combination of {name and age } found duplicate can be drop.  Expected result will be : List(Pet(cow,mow,2),Pet("hen", "kiwi", 2), Pet("horse", "kiwi", 1))

Comment: @santanumohanty, I don't understand your comment, you said that the expected output is `List(Pet("cow", "mow", 2))` which is provided by my answer.

Comment: Your above answer is correct and best solution to get List(Pet("cow", "mow", 2)). I am just asking if I  want to enhance to  drop species if found duplicate or combination of {name and age } found duplicate to drop. Then above example Expected result will be : List(Pet(cow,mow,2),Pet("hen", "kiwi", 2), Pet("horse", "kiwi", 1)).Can I do it on above code to modify by passing multiple feilds in group by

Comment: if I want to drop duplicate on a combination of {name and age } ,what will be the changes you think

Comment: not working for me if i add age     val namesToRemove = pets.groupBy(rec => (rec.name, rec.age)).filter(_._2.length > 1).keySet

Comment: @santanumohanty see https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/zXtlf6sYRwWa9ygyQbPH1w/3

Answer (score 2):

Not terribly efficient, but concise and easy to understand. (`foldLeft()` not needed.)

```
val species = pets.groupBy(_.species)
val names   = pets.groupBy(_.name)
pets.filter(p => species(p.species).length + 
                 names(p.name).length == 2)
//res0: List[Pet] = List(Pet(cow,mow,2))
```

If a `species` designation cannot appear in a `name` string, and a `name` string cannot appear as a `species` then this can be condensed.

```
val groups = pets.groupBy(_.species) ++ pets.groupBy(_.name)
pets.filter(p => groups(p.species).length + 
                 groups(p.name).length == 2)
```

---

If you want lists of both unique elements and all the non-unique elements...

```
val (unique, dups) =
  pets.partition(p => groups(p.species).length +
                      groups(p.name).length == 2)
```

Comment: can I add a println what has been drop?